# AWS Lambda done callback() function in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

The microservice-http-endpoint starter function in Lambda contains the following code to end the function:

```
const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
```

After writing a Lambda-only API with a few endpoints I found myself with this same code in all my functions. My first instinct was to put this into a module to make the code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) but if I do that the `callback()` function will become out of scope.

I am only returning JSON from my functions so this would be the only possible Content-Type in my specific use-case.

How are people dealing with this? Is there a practical (and elegant) way to encapsulate this code somehow? Or maybe a better alternative?

Comment: Just set `global.callback = callback` as the first line of your Lambda handler function and then it will never be out of scope.

Comment: @idbehold sending this to global feels iffy. Especially something so generic as "callback".

Comment: But Lambda container instances will only run your handler one at a time. If you invoke a Lambda function and then try to invoke the same Lambda function a second time before the first finishes, the second invocation will get a brand new container to run in. Only once your handler function has finished (or timed out) will that container be available again. So the global really shouldn't matter in the context of a Lambda function. You could always change the global name to something more specific if it makes you feel better `global.MY_SUPER_SECRET_CALLBACK = callback`.

Answer (score 1):

Just nest the functions:

```
const regularize = (awsCallback) => (err, res) => {
  awsCallback(...perYourAboveCode(err, res))
};
```

A handler could then look like:

```
const myHandler = (event, context, awsCallback) => {
  const callback = regularize(awsCallback);
};
```